$C^1$ convex function on a compact set is Lipschitz continuous
Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and convex and let $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ convex function. I wish to use the $C^1$ characterisation of convexity, i.e., $$f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)(y-x), \forall x, y \in K \tag{1},$$
to show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $K$.
On one hand, I observe that $(1)$ may be re-arranged to give
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(y) \leq \nabla f(x)(x-y).
\end{align}
If it is true that
\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |\nabla f(x)(x-y)| \tag{2},
\end{align}
then I may use Cauchy-Schwarz and the Extreme Value Theorem to conclude
\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |\nabla f(x)(x-y)| \leq |\nabla f(x)||x-y|\leq M|x-y|,
\end{align}
where $M = \max_{\Omega}{\nabla f(x)}$. However, I am not sure how to proceed in the case that $(2)$ does not hold, so that instead we have
\begin{align}
|\nabla f(x)(x-y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|?
\end{align}
How might I handle this case?
*Edited: The definition of $K$.

Your argument doesn't work if $K$ isn't convex. To replace (2) you should use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the triangle inequality for integrals.

(2) is not true for $f(x) = x^2/2$ (take $y=x+1$, $x>0$, then $f(x) - f(y) = 2x+1$, $\nabla f(x)(y-x)= 2x$.

The inequality (2) is not true in general for convex $f$: Take $f(x) = x^2$, $y=x+1$, $x>0$, then $f(y)- f(x) = 2x+1$, while $\nabla f(x)(y-x) = 2x$.
Since $f$ is $C^1$ on the compact set, there is $M>0$ such that $|\nabla f(x) |\le M$ for all $x\in K$. Using fundamental theorem, we get Lipschitz continuity:
$$
|f(y) - f(x)| = |\int_0^1 \nabla f(x+s(y-x))(y-x) ds | \le M |x-y|.
$$
